# Using the result of a Jquery function and save to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small script that returns the width and height of my Window, what I need is to save the result to a PHP session variable.

My script

```
var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;


if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
{
   viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
   viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}
```

like

```
$_SESSION['w'] = viewportwidth
$_SESSION['h'] = viewportheight
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @Epodax is correct you need to use Jquery Ajax for it

Answer (score 1):

you Can easily get this done using Ajax

JS / Client Side code

```js
$().ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    method  : "POST",
    url     : "capture.php",
    data    : { height: window.screen.availHeight, width: window.screen.availWidth }
  })  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And for Server Side it will be Like

```
session_start()

$_SESSION['h'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
$_SESSION['w'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
  var viewportwidth;
  var viewportheight;

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",  
      url: 'fileupload.php',
      data: viewportwidth,
      processData: false,
      // ... Other options like success, error and etc
  });
```

You can also create a variable which includes a complete string and pass that variable in **'data'** tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/sample.php",
          data: { width: viewportwidth,height:viewportheight }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
           //your response code here
}
```

in sample.php

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['w'] = $_POST['width'];
    $_SESSION['h'] = $_POST['height'];
?>
```